# How to tell rsync to skip files on a damaged hard drive block, instead of being stuck trying to read it

Tags: macos, rsync

I am trying to recover files from a disk that has hardware errors.

The disk was repaired by disk utility, but it told me that the disk is damaged, so I need to backup everything before a failure will happen.

So I tried to copy the files via finder, but it gets stuck. Tried other utilities and they get stuck trying to copy the files, when the head hits the damaged block.

So I tried with rsync, and it seems to work; but it takes forever when I hit a bad block.

So I was wondering, if there is a way to tell Rsync to not even bother with a file, if it takes too long?Either I can specify the number of try with each file, or how long it needs to try for each file?

I am not sure how long this drive will last honestly, so I want to get all the data off ASAP, while I can still mount it and see the data on it in finder.

This is what I am using as command; please advice if there is any way to reduce the try on a file, so I can have rsync to try to read the damaged blocks, but avoid to get stuck on a specific sector for too long.

```
rsync -arv -e--ignore-errors --partial-dir=/Volumes/backup/partial /Volumes/work /Volumes/backup
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the drive has damaged sectors you are better of trying to image the drive with something like `dd_rescue`, it has advanced features to cope with bad sectors.

Comment: I think @jmreicha has the right idea, but in the future, if you have rsync technical questions, friendly gurus are available on the rsync list: https://lists.samba.org/mailman/listinfo/rsync

Answer (score 14):

Short answer: **`rsync` it is not the right tool to be used in this case: its use can be even harmful.**
Use `ddrescue` instead (better than `dd_rescue`). It is able to do what you are asking for.

---

If the disk is physically damaged, there is the possibility to [*brick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_%28electronics%29) it with any attempt to repair it.

It is not only a question about the use of **your time**, when `rsync` seems to hang forever approaching a damaged sector. The problem is that with repeated operations an irreparable failure can happens, and then you will be not anymore able to to rescue your data without expensive parts replacement (always if it will be still possible and you will not have *bricked* your *HDD*).

In this case the most safe procedure I found is

1. To create a **raw image** on another not broken disk.
2. To create a **copy** of that image.
3. To **work on the copy to fix the *filesystem* and to rescue the files**.

*Why the copy?* Because if it fails something in the *filesystem* fixing step you can always start again without the need to touch again the original damaged *HDD*.

I suggest you to use [`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html), to do the raw disk image, defects included, because it works fine even in case of read errors.

---

**How to do it with `ddrescue`**

You can use `ddrescue` exactly as you would like to use `rsync`, skipping the damaged sectors without retrying or splitting them, copying as much data as possible.
This command is here below (instead of `/dev/hda1` you will put your device):

```
ddrescue --no-split /dev/hda1 imagefile logfile
```

After that you have done this first passage (the *faster one*), you can try to refine it trying to access for 3 times in case of error.

```
ddrescue --direct --max-retries=3 /dev/hda1 imagefile logfile
```

You can continue to refine the image repeating the `ddrescue` command invocations with other options, trying each time to extract more data (see the references). When you will finish you can create the copy (if you have all the needed space) and then to fix the *filesystem*.

Note that the raw image will be as big as the original *HDD*.
You can find on internet,  on this and on other sites of StackExchange many *questions&answers* about how to rescue data with `ddrescue` or other tools.

**References:**

- On [*"Forensics Wiki"*](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue)
- On [*"What's the difference between ddrescue, gddrescue, and dd_rescue?"*](https://askubuntu.com/a/211579/196535)
- On internet [*"LINUX - dd_rescue VS ddrescue (gddrescue BEST)"*](http://www.kossboss.com/linux---dd_rescue-vs-ddrescue)

Comment: indeed dd_rescue is the way to go. I had it in my original reply, 2 years ago; but for some reasons someone decided that I could not answer my own question :) Thanks for the reply and awesome details

Comment: @newbiez: Instead I had a serious disk problem with my almost bricked main _HDD_... so I met `ddrescue` and its friends :-) About your answer only a word: _weird_... post it again and if someone will try to close again I will vote yes to reopen (I never used that new __power__ :D)

Comment: The --no-split option was removed in newer versions of ddrescue. Use --no-scrape instead. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ddrescue/2015-09/msg00001.html

Answer (score 8):

I found this topic while was searching for a solution to save data from a failing SD-card (Ubuntu 20.04).

[The answer](https://superuser.com/a/980279/1186802) of [Hastur](https://superuser.com/users/257269/hastur) is awesome although the commands don't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Based on [Grmpfhmbl](https://superuser.com/users/448392/grmpfhmbl) comment and `ddrescue --help`

- the `--no-split` flag was removed so can use `--no-scrape` instead

  > -n, --no-scrape                skip the scraping phase

```bsh
ddrescue --no-scrape /dev/hda1 imagefile logfile
```

And the command to refine has changed, too.

- use `-d` or `--idirect` for direct disk access for the input file

  > -d, --idirect                  use direct disc access for input file
- instead of `--max-retries=3` we can use `-r` or `--retry-passes=<n>`

  > -r, --retry-passes=         exit after  retry passes (-1=infinity) [0]

```bsh
ddrescue --idirect --retry-passes=3 /dev/hda1 imagefile logfile
```

I assume no credit for this post, it's just an update of the answer of [Hastur](https://superuser.com/users/257269/hastur).