# Different partitions listed by lsblk and fdisk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, mount

I'm having issues mounting an external WD 4TB USB HD. It has two 2GB partitions, one NTFS and the other exfat. This has been my backup disk on a RPI4 and worked well for over 5 years until yesterday when it didn't mount after a reboot. After some tests on different systems I got it out of the WD MyBook enclosure and connected it to a generic enclosure and to my main Linux system. I'm using EndeavourOS but also tried mounting it on Raspbian and MacOS...

When I run `lsblk` I get my three disks but the USB drive (sda) don't show its partitions:

```
sda                    3,6T 
nvme1n1              931,5G 
├─nvme1n1p1 vfat       300M /boot/efi
└─nvme1n1p2 ext4     931,2G /
nvme0n1                1,8T 
└─nvme0n1p1 ext4       1,8T /media/nvme2tb
```

But if I run `fdisk -l /dev/sda` then I get the partitions (with a weird size):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3,64 TiB, 4000753476096 bytes, 7813971633 sectors
Disk model:                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9f002533

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1               1     76805     76805  37,5M ee GPT
/dev/sda2           77056 488395263 488318208 232,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       488428032 976745983 488317952 232,8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

If I try to mount any of its partitions I get the same error mentioning that the partitions don't exist (they are neither on my /dev/ directory):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/test_drive -t vfat -o rw
mount: /media/test_drive: special device /dev/sda3 does not exist.
   dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

And `dmesg` doesn't show anything strange:

```
[35454.834257] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[35454.850855] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0562, bcdDevice=22.01
[35454.850861] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[35454.850862] usb 2-4: Product: External
[35454.850863] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: JMicron
[35454.850865] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: DD5641988389A
[35454.890676] scsi host6: uas
[35454.891235] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron                   2201 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[35454.893866] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] 7813971633 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[35454.893868] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[35454.894018] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[35454.894019] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[35454.894303] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[35454.894742] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
[35454.894744] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (4096 bytes)
[35462.811048] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

Is there any other test/program I can do/run to check if the drive is fully dead? I'm hoping at least to be able to recover some of the data.

Thanks

Comment: That is quite large for a 32-bit partition

Comment: TESTDISK https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk  and .....  Using fsck to Find and Repair Disk Errors and Bad Sectors  https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-use-fsck-to-fix-disk-problems/    Important! 
Unmount the target disk first. You risk corrupting your file system and losing data if you run fsck on an active disk.

Comment: If you have a spare 4tb disk (or data is worth enough to justify buying one) use ddrescue to clone the disk as much as possible. Then testdisk - and if that fails use photorec to look fir usable fragments.

Comment: I'd place a bet on the WD Mybook hardware somehow malfunctioned and a write to the disk ended up with garbage. Attempt recovery using ddrescue and testdisk. Occasionally i feel `$ gnome-disks` might also tell you some detail more.

Comment: [Self citing](https://superuser.com/a/980279/257269). The command line switches are a bit old (see the other answer for that), but the procedure steps are still valid. First make a byte-by-byte disk image, then if you can, copy the resulting image and work on this last copy. In case of irreversible operations on the copy of the image you can always recreate it. In case copying is not possible, work directly on the image, just more carefully.  `KDE partition manager` and `gparted` may give you some info more...

Comment: Can you show a `head -c 512 /dev/sda | hexdump -C`?

Comment: Also, can you attempt to `losetup -r -b 4096 -P -f /dev/sda` and then run `fdisk -l` on the resulting /dev/loop device? (Run losetup alone to determine which loop device it created.)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511148/108618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your case.
First, a successfully running configuration fails.
Second:

You fell into the sector size trap that all manufacturers of ready-to-use external enclosure with disks prepare without warning their users.

Your WD enclosure most probable contains some converting electronics emulating a sector size of 4096 bytes.

In reality your disk has a logical sector size of 512 bytes at the hard disk interface which would restrict the partition size to 2 TB under a MBR partitioning scheme. By adding emulating electronics your disk appears as a disk with a sector size of 4096 byte. This sector size allows using even the old MBR partitioning scheme which makes the external disk compatible with legacy operating systems.

To verify this claim you could put the disk back into the enclosure and verify its sector size again using the mentioned `fdisk -l /dev/sda` command. It should then show a size of 4096 bytes.

When connecting the naked disk directly to a computer, the size of 512 byte appears and the computer will search your first partition at the wrong location of 77056 times 512 bytes instead of 77054 times 4096 bytes.
Use the command proposed by user1686 in one of the comments above

[...
***Also, can you attempt to losetup -r -b 4096 -P -f /dev/sda and then run fdisk -l on the resulting /dev/loop device? (Run losetup alone to determine which loop device it created.) –
user1686***
...]
source: user1686

This will create an additional virtual device that is aware of the intial sector size of 4096 bytes.

The instructions above should explain and heal your second issue.
As for your first issue,

1. read out your SMART parameters using smartmontools into a file and post the file here for a quick check of possible hardware issues.
2. Duplicate your possibly failing or even dying disk using ddrescue.

If you have a disk with a logical sector size of 4096 bytes at the interface as duplicating target, no special tricks are needed for mounting provided that your original WD enclosure shows a sector size of 4096 bytes.

Finally, you can continue with data rescue efforts.

Comment: I tried putting back the hd in its original WD MyBook enclosure but it didn't show even with lsblk, so I guess the electronic component of the enclosure was the main fail. On the other hand, I put it again in the generic enclosure and tried with the losetup command and was able to mount the /dev/loop... of both partitions without any issue (read-only). Now I can extract all the data and move it to another drive. THANKS!!!!!